# Turning Facebook htm file into dataframe in R

Tags: r, regex, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to extract my Facebook chat messages from a .htm file into a proper dataframe. `Rvest` has served me well by extracting the html nodes (user, meta, p) into vectors then df. However, I'm stuck at this part:

```
<div class="thread">
    John, My Name"
    <div class="message">
        <div class="message_header">
            <span class="user">My Name</span>
            <span class="meta">Thursday, April 9, 2015 at 12:55am UTC+07</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>Hello, how are you today</p>


//Other <div class = "message">
//Other <div class = "thread">
```

"Thread" marks my conversation with a person, and "message" shows my messages. Asthe class "user" sometime only shows "My Name", and not "John" or "Jack", I need to extract the string "John, My name" as another variable, and ignore all the text in the subsequent nested "message" classes.

I suspect that regex, which I'm clueless about, is needed for this. I also tried using `Xpath` for html_nodes, but  `/html/body/div[**x**]/div[**y**]/div[**z**]/text()` does not allow me to dynamically change the xpaths to read all the thread classes (x, y, z vary, and it's a 160mb htm file).

Any help is appreciated!

Edit: My code:

```
library(rvest)
library(XML)
url <- read_html("messages.htm")

users<-html_nodes(x = url, css = ".user") %>% html_text()
date<-html_nodes(x = url, css = ".meta") %>% html_text()
#Repeat

df <- cbind(users, date, etc.)     

#Extracting the names of the thread with xpath
threadget <- function(n){
  html_text(html_node(url, xpath = sub("n", n, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[n]/text()")))
}
for (n in c(seq(1,553,1))){thread[n] = threadget(n)}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please be sure to edit your question to show the code you've tried.  Can't you target the divs with class "thread" and get their text directly doing something like `html_nodes(example, xpath = '*//div[@class = "thread"]/text()[1]')`?

Comment: Thanks @Jota! That was exactly what I needed. Would you have any recommendation on where to read up on `xpath`?

Comment: You could check out https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xpath/ and https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my code after implementing @Jota suggestion

```
#Finding the length of each thread for looping using html_children() and length()
list <- html_nodes(url, css = ".thread")
count <- sapply(list, html_children)
threadlength <- sapply(count, length)
#Extracting the names of the thread using xpath
threadlist <- html_nodes(url2, xpath = '*//div[@class = "thread"]/text()[1]') %>% html_text()

#Creating the thread column
#x indicates how many rows a thread topic should be duplicated. 
#y is used to subset the thread column. 
#z is used to close the inner loop, moving to the next thread topic
thread <- c()
n <- 0
y <- 0
for (x in threadlength) {
  z <- 0
  n <- n+1
  repeat{
    y <- y+1
    z <- z+1
    thread[y] <- threadlist[n]
    if (z == x){
      break
    }
  }
}
```